# Get index of map of strings in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a map of strings in Terraform. I want to produce 3 `tpl` files, that use all of the values from the map at the same time. for each file, i need to know what is the current index in the map (`server_id` variable).

```
variable "ip_map" {
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    "subnet-abc" = "10.2.0.5"
    "subnet-hij" = "10.2.16.5"
    "subnet-xyz" = "10.2.32.5"
  }
}


data "template_file" "xml_config" {
  for_each = var.ip_map
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/config.xml.tpl")
  vars = {
    host       = each.value
    server_id  = ???
    server_id1 = index(keys(var.ip_map), element(keys(var.ip_map), 0)) + 1
    server_id2 = index(keys(var.ip_map), element(keys(var.ip_map), 1)) + 1
    server_id3 = index(keys(var.ip_map), element(keys(var.ip_map), 2)) + 1
   ....
   ....
  }
}
```

I tried to use the following expression for `server_id`, but got wrong index numbers. then i found out that map has no index.

```
index(values(var.ip_map), each.value) + 1
```

I need that in the first iteration, the server_id value will be equal to `server_id1`...in the second iteration, the `server_id` value will be equal to `server_id2`, etc. I'm sure it's easier than i think but i still need an help with that. Anyone can suggest how to do that?

Here is an example:

```
The template values of server 1 will be:
     vars = {
        host       = "10.2.0.5"
        server_id  = 1
        host1      = "10.2.0.5"
        server_id1 = 1
        host2      = "10.2.16.5"
        server_id2 = 2
        host3      = "10.2.32.5"
        server_id3 = 3
      }

The template values of server 2 will be:
     vars = {
        host       = "10.2.16.5"
        server_id  = 2
        host1      = "10.2.0.5"
        server_id1 = 1
        host2      = "10.2.16.5"
        server_id2 = 2
        host3      = "10.2.32.5"
        server_id3 = 3
      }

The template values of server 3 will be:
     vars = {
        host       = "10.2.32.5"
        server_id  = 3
        host1      = "10.2.0.5"
        server_id1 = 1
        host2      = "10.2.16.5"
        server_id2 = 2
        host3      = "10.2.32.5"
        server_id3 = 3
      }
```

Please note that the order itself doesn't matter as long as the values are consistent in all of the template files (For example, server_id1 can be any IP , but it should be consistent).

Comment: So are you wanting to populate a template with both (a) *all* of the pairs in the map, and (b) also just one of the pairs at a time? So that each output file "belongs to" one of the items but also "knows about" all the others?

Comment: Also, do you need to be using TF 0.11, or are you using (or able to use) 0.12? If so, you can use the [templatefile](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile) function instead of the `template_file` data source.

Comment: Maps do not have indices, and they do not preserve order. So you can't relay on that. You have to re-design your code not to use a map, or require an index.

Comment: @lxop correct. that's what i'm looking for. currently everything work as expected, except the `server_id` parameter. I'm using TF v1.0.3.

Comment: @Marcin the order itself is less important. I just want that the templates population will be consistent with some order. I don't care if some ip will be the first or the last, as long as the values will be consistent in all of the template files. is it possible?

Comment: Yes I think this will be entirely possible. Can you please update the question with an example of exactly what you want the vars part of one of the files to be? And is this definitely always only 3 servers, or should it work for any number? If it's for any number, please be clear about what the vars should be called for each of the variable number of servers

Comment: @lxop I've add an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map in Terraform is inherently unordered and so there isn't any specific "index" to retrieve for a map element.

However, if you just want each element to be assigned a unique number and it doesn't matter which is which then you can project your map into a list of key/value pairs, which will cause Terraform to use its default iteration sequence of keys in lexical order:

```
locals {
  ip_list = tolist([
    for k, v in var.ip_map :
    [ k, v ]
  ])
}
```

If `var.ip_map` matches the default value you showed in your question then `local.ip_list` would have the following value:

```
tolist([
  ["subnet-abc", "10.2.0.5"],
  ["subnet-hij", "10.2.16.5"],
  ["subnet-xyz", "10.2.32.5"],
])
```

You can then project that back to a map of objects with each element having an additional attribute tracking the index from the intermediate list:

```
locals {
  ip_map = tomap({
    for idx, pair in local.ip_list : pair[0] => {
      ip_address = pair[1]
      index      = idx
    }
  })
}
```

(I used `idx` directly here, but you could use `idx + 1` if you want the numbers to be one-based instead of zero-based.)

Continuing from the example values above, `local.ip_map` would be:

```
tomap({
  "subnet-abc" = {
    ip_address = "10.2.0.5"
    index      = 0
  }
  "subnet-hij" = {
    ip_address = "10.2.16.5"
    index      = 1
  }
  "subnet-xyz" = {
    ip_address = "10.2.32.5"
    index      = 2
  }
})
```

If you use *this* value in your `for_each` argument, then:

- `each.key` will be the key, like `"subnet-abc"`
- `each.value.ip_address` will be the IP address, like `"10.2.0.5"`
- `each.value.index` will be the index, like `0`

Note that if you do this then deleting `subnet-hij` in the future will cause `subnet-xyz` to be renumbered as `index = 1`, and so you'll need to either ensure that you never delete a subnet or write the rest of your configuration so that it will not be disrupted by the renumbering.

Answer (score 1):

The main key to solving your problem is to separate the shared part of the `vars` map from the item-specific part. They are both based on the `ip_map` variable, but you need to treat them separately.

From your added example, it looks like the labels for the servers are not being used, just the IP addresses. So we can convert the map to a simple list of IP addresses with

```
locals {
  ip_list = [for k, v in var.ip_map: v]
}
```

Then we want to create an instance of your template for each IP address in that list. For that, we convert the list back to a map, but with a simple index integer for a key:

```
data "template_file" "xml_config" {
  for_each = {for idx, v in local.ip_list: idx => v}

  template = file("${path.module}/templates/config.xml.tpl")
  vars = {
    host       = each.value
    server_id  = each.key + 1
    # More to come here
  }
}
```

Next, we need the vars that are common between all the template instances. We can prepare these in a local variable:

```
locals {
  all_servers = merge([for idx, v in local.ip_list: {
    format("host%d", idx + 1)      = v
    format("server_id%d", idx + 1) = idx + 1
  }]...)
}
```

This block creates a map like `{host1: ..., server_id1: 1}` for each IP address, using its index for the server number, and puts them in a list. Then it merges them all into a single map with `merge(list_of_maps...)`. The `...` syntax turns the single list into a sequence of arguments for the `merge` function.

Finally, we put it all together:

```
variable "ip_map" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "subnet-abc" = "10.2.0.5"
    "subnet-hij" = "10.2.16.5"
    "subnet-xyz" = "10.2.32.5"
  }
}

locals {
  ip_list = [for k, v in var.ip_map : v]
  all_servers = merge([for idx, v in local.ip_list : {
    format("host%d", idx + 1)      = v
    format("server_id%d", idx + 1) = idx + 1
  }]...)
}

data "template_file" "xml_config" {
  for_each = { for idx, v in local.ip_list : idx => v }

  template = file("${path.module}/templates/config.xml.tpl")
  vars = merge({
    host      = each.value
    server_id = each.key + 1
    },
    local.all_servers
  )
}
```

We again use `merge()` to combine the host-specific details with the common details for the `vars` argument. Checking the results, we see that the vars are as required:

```
output "template1" {
  value = data.template_file.xml_config.1
}

-------------------------

  + template1 = {
      + filename = null
      + id       = "..."
      + rendered = <<-EOT
            (...)
        EOT
      + template = <<-EOT
            (...)
        EOT
      + vars     = {
          + "host"       = "10.2.16.5"
          + "host1"      = "10.2.0.5"
          + "host2"      = "10.2.16.5"
          + "host3"      = "10.2.32.5"
          + "server_id"  = "2"
          + "server_id1" = "1"
          + "server_id2" = "2"
          + "server_id3" = "3"
        }
    }
```